# JavaScript: Save PDF in the 'Microsoft PDF reader'

Tags: javascript, pdf, microsoft-edge

my web app opens a PDF inside an Iframe. Users can then add texts, draw with digital ink and highlight text. As the PDF is rendered using the user's browser-engine, I recommend trying it with the latest Microsoft Edge.

I would like to save the edited PDF to the location I opened it from with the click of a button.

The PDF editor of the browser has a save feature, but users have to select the location first, and confirm that they are overwriting the file.

Is it even possible because Microsoft Edge seems to isolate the PDF process. When I open a PDF in Edge without my web app, I can simply click the save button, and it will be saved at the location I opened it.

I could not find any documentation for microsoft pdf editor and how to interact with it.

Full code of my project: https://github.com/joseftogo/PDF-Notes-Manager-Alpha

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with KJ's opinion. When you open a pdf on a website in Edge, you're actually view it **online**. So it's wrong to say *"save the edited PDF to the location I opened it"*, it's not opened from local file path. If you want to save it, you're not overwriting any file on your computer, you're **downloading** a new file to your computer, so you have to select the location first. It's the necessary process.

For the situation you say, *"When I open a PDF in Edge without my web app, I can simply click the save button, and it will be saved at the location I opened it."* I think that's when you open a **local** pdf file in Edge. At that time, Edge is just a viewer, and the pdf is already existed on your computer so of course you can overwrite that file directly.